# Steps to upload an iPhone application to the AppStore

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

I want to know the basic steps for uploading my iPhone application to AppStore.

How do I make a provisioning profile using a certificate and what other settings do I need to do to upload an application?

I have just made an application on my iMac using Xcode and the iPhone SDK V2.2.1. What do I need to do for uploading it on the Apple iTunes store?

I am member of that and I have also a distribution certificate.

Comment: See the link contain full Step wise tutorial 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/16747740/846372

Answer (score 70, accepted):

This [arstechnica article](http://arstechnica.com/apple/guides/2009/04/app-store-lessons-dealing-with-pink-uploads-of-doom.ars) describes the basic steps:

> Start by visiting the program portal
>   and make sure that your developer
>   certificate is up to date. It expires
>   every six months and, if you haven't
>   requested that a new one be issued,
>   you cannot submit software to App
>   Store. For most people experiencing
>   the "pink upload of doom," though,
>   their certificates are already valid.
>   What next?
>
> Open your Xcode project and check that
>   you've set the active SDK to one of
>   the device choices, like Device - 2.2.
>   Accidentally leaving the build
>   settings to Simulator can be a big
>   reason for the pink rejection. And
>   that happens more often than many
>   developers would care to admit.
>
> Next, make sure that you've chosen a
>   build configuration that uses your
>   distribution (not your developer)
>   certificate. Check this by
>   double-clicking on your target in the
>   Groups & Files column on the left of
>   the project window. The Target Info
>   window will open. Click the Build tab
>   and review your Code Signing Identity.
>   It should be iPhone Distribution:
>   followed by your name or company name.
>
> You may also want to confirm your
>   application identifier in the
>   Properties tab. Most likely, you'll
>   have set the identifier properly when
>   debugging with your developer
>   certificate, but it never hurts to
>   check.
>
> The top-left of your project window
>   also confirms your settings and
>   configuration. It should read
>   something like "Device - 2.2 |
>   Distribution". This shows you the
>   active SDK and configuration.
>
> If your settings are correct but you
>   still aren't getting that upload
>   finished properly, clean your builds.
>   Choose Build > Clean (Command-Shift-K)
>   and click Clean. Alternatively, you
>   can manually trash the build folder in
>   your Project from Finder. Once you've
>   cleaned, build again fresh.
>
> If this does not produce an app that
>   when zipped properly loads to iTunes
>   Connect, quit and relaunch Xcode. I'm
>   not kidding. This one simple trick
>   solves more signing problems and "pink
>   rejections of doom" than any other
>   solution already mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

Apple provides detailed, illustrated instructions covering every step of the process.  Log in to the iPhone developer site and click the "program portal" link.  In the program portal you'll find a link to the program portal user's guide, which is a really good reference and guide on this topic.

Comment: The instructions are not updated for XCode 4! It is now elusive as to how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your singing identity IN YOUR TARGET properties is correct.  This one over-rides what you have in your project properties.

Also: I dunno if this is true - but I wasn't getting emails detailing my binary rejections when I did the "ready for binary upload" from a PC - but I DID get an email when I did this on the MAC

Answer (score 0):

## Xcode 9

If this is your first time to submit an app, I recommend going ahead and reading through the full [Apple iTunes Connect documentation](https://developer.apple.com/support/itunes-connect/) or reading one of the following tutorials:

- [How to Submit an iOS App to the App Store](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-submit-an-ios-app-to-the-app-store--mobile-16812)
- [How to Submit An App to Apple: From No Account to App Store](https://www.raywenderlich.com/127936/submit-an-app-part-1)

However, those materials are cumbersome when you just want a quick reminder of the steps. My answer to that is below:

## Step 1: Create a new app in iTunes Connect

Sign in to iTunes Connect and go to My Apps. Then click the "+" button and choose New App.

[image]

Then fill out the basic information for a new app. The app bundle id needs to be the same as the one you are using in your Xcode project. There is probably a better was to name the [SKU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710512/itunes-connect-how-to-choose-a-good-sku), but I've never needed it and I just use the bundle id.

[image]

Click **Create** and then go on to Step 2.

## Step 2: Archive your app in Xcode

Choose the **Generic iOS Device** from the active scheme menu.

[image]

Then go to **Product > Archive**.

[image]

You may have to wait a little while for Xcode to finish archiving your project. After that you will be shown a dialog with your archived project. You can select **Upload to the App Store...** and follow the prompts.

I sometimes have to repeat this step a few times because I forgot to include something. Besides the upload wait, it isn't a big deal. Just keep doing it until you don't get any more errors.

## Step 3: Finish filling out the iTunes Connect info

Back in iTunes Connect you will need to complete all the required information and resources.

[image]

Just go through all the menu options and make sure that you have everything entered that needs to be.

## Step 4: Submit

In iTunes Connect, under your app's Prepare for Submission section, click **Submit for Review**. That's it. Give it about a week to be accepted (or rejected), but it might be faster.