# How do I compile my app for submission to the app store?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I have an iPhone app that I've developed and I'm ready to submit it to the app store.  I've read the iTunes Connect Developer Guide, but there's nowhere that specifies exactly how to go from an app in XCode to a binary uploaded to the app store.

Is anyone who has done this able to guide me here?

Thanks!
Bjorn

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/796482/steps-to-upload-an-iphone-application-to-the-appstore

Answer (score 4):

Go to your Target (The blue print looking thing) and go to "Build settings" make sure that the code signing is under "Distribution" and the mobile provisioning profile you are using is set to "App store". This can be checked by logging into the developer portal and looking at the provisions you have under the "Distribution Tab". Make sure to do "Clean" then build the app.
Once done navigate over to the project folder and find the folder that has the xxx.app in it.
Zip this folder (Since .app is a folder its self) and you are done!
You are ready to submit!
Just make sure to double check the guidelines for submission since the approval process is really slow (up to 4 Days!) so if you get rejected you have to wait the wait again.

Answer (score 0):

[may be this will help you](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/app_distribution_overview/publishing_to_the_app_store/)

here examples with images