# Steps to upload an iPhone application to the AppStore in xcode4

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4, xcodebuild, xcode3to4

as xcode 3 and xcode 4 is totally different.
i'm a bit lost to submit app to app store.

1. Do i still need to duplicate "Release" to create "iphoneDistrubition" configuration.
   Or can I straight away use Release?
2. Is Archive in xcode4  = Build in xcode3 for the purpose of submission app.
3. If Archive = Build, the icon of the app is very blur in xcode4 organizer. Is that normal?
4. Is there any other additional steps to follow in xcode4 to submit app to appstore.

Thanks for any help. =)

Comment: Yesterday I submitted to app store via the archive function, I validated and everything was OK, today I got: "Invalid Signature - Make sure you have signed your application with a distribution certificate" mail from Apple. I am not sure but I think I must also set the build configuration to "Distribution" for the archive scheme. Is there a guide somewhere?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Steps to upload an iPhone application to the AppStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796482/steps-to-upload-an-iphone-application-to-the-appstore)

Answer (score 7):

Xcode 4 makes it easier to submit.

As you have discovered, all you have to do is archive.

The blurry icon is expected behavior as it is a bigger square than on the device.

After you archive you will have the option to `submit` to the app store, just make sure you are using the right provisioning profile and you will be good to go.

It is useful to know xcode 4 also allows you to do the validation test before submitting so when you submit you are certain there are no problems.

Hope it helps!

Comment: so.. after i change the provisioning profile to distribution profile in release config... then archive, validate, submit... right?

Comment: exactly, if your binary passes the local verification you can be confident it wil pass the validation done by itunes connect.

Comment: Can you go a bit more into detail what you mean by "so.. after i change the provisioning profile to distribution profile in release config..."?

Comment: you want to make sure that the Code Signing in Target, Build Settings, is set to the app store distribution profile