# How to submit the app to app store?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, itunes

I recently made my first iphone app.

I am completely new into iphone programming.

How to submit the app to app store?

I will be better helped with some detailed explanation as I am a noobee.

Comment: Seriously, you couldn't do a google search, or go to Apple's site to find this answer? Can't wait to download your app! NOT!

Comment: give us the project folder and we'll post the app up for you ... >:) *evil grin*

Comment: Very Smart Lukman. But I am not dumb :D :D

Comment: possible duplicate of [Steps to upload an iPhone application to the AppStore in xcode4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401257/steps-to-upload-an-iphone-application-to-the-appstore-in-xcode4)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Steps to upload an iPhone application to the AppStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796482/steps-to-upload-an-iphone-application-to-the-appstore)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three best links I could find are :

http://www.mahalo.com/answers/what-is-the-process-to-submit-an-application-to-itunes

http://help.appmakr.com/entries/218997-how-to-upload-your-app-to-itunes-connect-using-application-loader

http://www.weston-fl.com/blog/?p=2442

Comment: Make sure you read the App Review Guidelines before you submit! Submitting is not as easy as it should be-- I had to google stuff like crazy.

Comment: Another good link, a step by step guide with pictures:  http://www.cannonballbounce.com/content/sumbitting-your-iphone-game-app-store

Answer (score 2):

You'll find your detailed explanation in the [iOS Developer Program User Guide](http://adcdownload.apple.com/ios/ios_developer_program_user_guide/ios_developer_program_user_guide__standard_program_v2.7__final_9110.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Go to developer.apple.com/ios, log in, look on the right for itunes connect, click on "manage apps", click "add new application" and follow directions for submission. You must be a registered apple developer and have already paid the developer fee.

Comment: Seriously, it's by far not that simple. You need to know heck of a LOT of things about build configurations, certificates, code signing among MANY other highly technical things not covered at all on the iTunes Connect website. It is a pain, after all.

Comment: There is a how-to guide on each and every screen on the iTunes Connect website (there are tabs for Development, Distribution and HOW-TO), from creating certificates, provisioning profiles, adding devices, etc. There are hundreds of thousands of apps in the app store, it can't be THAT hard to follow instructions. Also, since at least XCode 4.2 you can submit directly from the XCode organizer. As an aside, if the OP asked a specific question, such as "XCode is giving X error" we could help, but a general "how do you submit" isn't going to get you anywhere except to the docs.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has excellent documentation:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/145-Distributing_Applications/distributing_applications.html

In summary:

1. Make sure your application is something of value.
2. Great a distribution provisioning profile in the developer portal.
3. Archive you application using this profile.
4. Log into iTunes Connect and add an application - there will be several pages of fields to fill out. Upload your application.
5. Wait for approval.

Comment: all of you forgot one important step: pay Apple $99 first :)