# Is there a tutorial for how to build correctly for the App Store?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, xcode4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to submit the app to app store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598347/how-to-submit-the-app-to-app-store)

I have access to all of the WWDC videos but haven't found one talking about how to actually make a correct build for the App Store. Especially the parts with code signing, entitlements, and what not. There are about a gazillion things to consider. The iTunes Connect Developer Guide is covering the assets like icons, Default.png, etc.

Is there a step-by-step checklist (or video that shows it) how to submit an app to the App Store, using the latest developer tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a step-by-step checklist (or video that shows it) how to
>   submit an app to the App Store, using the latest developer tools?

Yes. You'll find complete, up-to-date, step-by-step directions for building and submitting the app itself in the iOS Provisioning Portal under the [Distribution tab](http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/distribution/index.action).

You've already found the iTunes Connect Developer Guide, which covers preparing to submit the app. You should be familiar with the information in that guide, but don't let it scare you... iTunesConnect itself pretty much walks you through the process of preparing to submit.

Comment: Thanks. Well the iTunes Connect User Guide doesn't mention anything about disabling NSZombiesEnabled, which is absolutely crucial. I just know that by accident and it's likely that there are about a bunch of other things like this. It also doesn't talk about wether you need a release or distribution build among many other technical aspects of building a universal binary for the App Store. Gonna hava a look at that Distribution tab now. :-)

Comment: Zombies is a debugging tool -- you wouldn't want it enabled in *any* non-debug build, whether going to the App Store or not. The iTC guide and the portal will tell you how to prepare for and do the submission; the checklist @Harold linked gives you a large number of things to check before you even get to that point.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good resource:

https://ontestpad.com/library/201/ios-app-store-submission-checklist

Comment: I think the OP is asking for something different -- he/she seems to be looking for the necessary steps 1..n to build and submit an app. You've linked a checklist that's useful for avoiding a rejection. +1 anyway -- even if it's not what the OP asked for exactly, it looks like a very good thing to have on hand.

Comment: Thanks - you make a good point. The part of the question I zeroed in on was "There are about a gazillion things to consider" :) I should have stated the purpose of the response more clearly in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I **highly** suggest you watch a couple of videos from Lynda.com. They cover everything from A-Z about uploading a binary to Apple and everything you need to include and how to sign it. You can google "Lynda 7 Day Trial" and sign up for their free trial. Go to the iOS section of their training and watch the chapter "Submitting your App" (or its called something like that). Then cancel your trial before they charge your card, or you can stay a member if you like their program.

Heres a link for the trial: http://www.lynda.com/promo/trial/Default.aspx?lpk35=1854

It really really helps you understand what exactly Apple wants from you when uploading.

Comment: Although that video is good, it's using Xcode 3. Old stuff.