# Submitting application to app store?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I just finished making my first application and have tested it on the devices and all that good stuff. But I have been pulling my hair since this morning because I don't really know how to submit the application to the app store. Any help would be appreciated on this topic.

**Additional Info**

So now I am getting error "To submit or validate an application, you must first log in to iTunes Connect and provide information about the application you will be adding." Even though I have added an application to itunes connect and made sure that the app id is same in application the application's plist. please help me on this thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401257/steps-to-upload-an-iphone-application-to-the-appstore-in-xcode4

Comment: I have xcode 3 'cause my internet is too slow :/ sorry

Comment: Really, do try xcode 4, it's much easier to use.

Answer (score 2):

1. Log into the [iOS developer site](http://developer.apple.com/ios/) and enter the provisioning portal.
2. Click "Distribution" on the left side of the page.
3. Follow the instructions under the Prepare App tab.
4. You'll also want to read the [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf) (PDF).

Comment: Agreed.. Apple has very definitive and detailed instructions on how to submit applications to the App Store.  Try following those directions and then if you get stuck on something more specific, ask that question.

Comment: thanks for the answer please look at the question I am getting some error thanks

Comment: There's potentially a lot of information you have to provide before you submit an app. In addition to description, icons, etc. you may also need to provide bank info, ensure that you've accepted any recent changes to the developer agreement, etc. iTunesConnect should show the app as being ready to upload the application binary; if it doesn't, you've still got work to do somewhere.