# How to Archive and submit the app to app store Xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.2, store

Can someone help me step by step how to archive and submit the app to the app store. in Xcode 4.2 
I have been searching on YouTube and over the net they all are incomplete 
Please help me in detail

Comment: possible duplicate of [Steps to upload an iPhone application to the AppStore in xcode4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401257/steps-to-upload-an-iphone-application-to-the-appstore-in-xcode4)

Answer (score 4):

1. Make sure all your certificates are correct and are installed on your machine
2. Go to iTunes Connect and create a new application/build [delete as appropriate]
3. Run Build and Archive
4. Switch to the Organizer
5. Select the build that you've just completed
6. Press the Validate button
7. If that went well, press the Submit button

There are lots of things that can go wrong, unfortunately. But you give zero information on what you've tried or what's didn't work. Apple's documentation is pretty thorough. I'd recommend reading that rather than searching for random YouTube clips. Apple also allow you to download videos from many WWDC talks, including ones about using Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you are required to archive your app to submit to the App Store. The method I've used going back to 3.x is to show your product myApp.app in Finder, then compress it. It should zip the file up, and you can submit it through the Application Loader. Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you need application loader to upload even in Xcode 4.2 if yes where can i find ?

Comment: Pretty sure you need it. Should be link when you log in to iTunesConnect. You will need to set up your submission in ITC first, then use App Loader to submit against it. It is pretty easy once you have the app set up in ITC. Good Luck.

Comment: You can submit apps inside Xcode. There's little need for Application Loader any more. And yes, you need to archive your app before submission. This is basically just zipping it up.

Comment: Right, but you aren't required to submit via Xcode, the other methods still work. The question leaves out a lot of information.

Comment: @BillBrasky App Loader isn't working anymore for me. I being told i should upload via Xcode organizer.

Comment: We do both, Xcode direct upload (via Archive) and semi manual ZIP upload via Application Loader - both ways still work totally fine. Actually the latter way usually works best - fewer hidden caveats.

Comment: I just submitted an update a week ago using App Loader... using 4.2.1.

Answer (score 1):

Apple added video tutorials that explain exactly how to do this. Log in to iTunes connect using your iOS developer program credentials. Once you're logged in, go to "Manage You Apps". At the bottom of the page, there is a video tutorials section that has two tutorials - "Adding An App" and "Delivering Your Binary".

I believe these are what you're looking for.