# Fail to load app in the AppStore

Tags: ios, app-store

I create new app in iTunesConnection, and then trying to appload zip-archive with Application Downloader. But when i push "Deliver Your App" Downloader shows me this error:

[image]

But i got 2 apps, which "waiting for download"

[image]

What is the problem? Any ideas?

UPD. XCode shows me the same error

[image]

Comment: Do you have a "prepare for binary upload" button in your app's page ?

Comment: @Loïs Di Qual: Status - Prepare for Upload

Comment: Are you sure you are logged in with the right production apple-developer id ? Also check the user's privileges as the team member.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All was okay! The problem was in my proxy-internet. iTunesConnections doesn't work wuth proxy. That's why XCode and AppDownloader didn't see any information from my account.
Thnx all for your answers and comments.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your [project-name]-Info.plist file if it does contain correct bundle identifier.
Bundle identifier should match the one you configured in your provisioning profile for your app.

For instance: `com.mycompany.effecto`

Also make sure if you are using right provisioning profile for both apps.

**Edit:**

You application in itunesconnect need to be in 'waiting for upload' state and not in 'prepare for upload'. Please fill all required data in itunesconnect then your status will be updated.
You may need to click prepare for upload and fill all legal stuff in there.

Comment: i think, it doesn't matter for this step. application downloader doesnt compare my project and itunesconnection on this step

Comment: Why not using xcode to upload your app? With recent versions you can do that after archiving is done.

Comment: Take a look here [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dbabzWVvcvE) or here [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401257/steps-to-upload-an-iphone-application-to-the-appstore-in-xcode4)