# How do I setup a demo of my application for review when uploading to the app store?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I have a flutter app that is available on android. It is accessible only for users in a certain country and with a SIM card of that country. I am trying to upload it to the app store for IOS but they have rejected it as they can't log in for the reasons mentioned above. Is there any way to explain that to apple?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Steps to upload an iPhone application to the AppStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796482/steps-to-upload-an-iphone-application-to-the-appstore)

Comment: It doesn't. It's not the uploading part that's the problem. It's that the logging in process is with a USSD and required your phone number to be registered in our database. So how can apple get past that to check the app for upload?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a demo account, and in your code, if it is the demo account, skip the country and sim check. When submitting, enter this account's credentials under the "Demo account" section in AppStoreConnect.

Comment: I thought about that. but, there's nothing a user enters for logging in. You just click on a button, and the app makes a USSD call to see if you are in our system and lets you through.

Comment: That's a tough one. The only thing that comes to mind is: if the check fails, after tapping the button, I suppose you have some explanatory label or alert that says something about it. In that case, next to this text, you can add a button entitled "Use a demo account". When this button is tapped, prompt for a password (you can also notify that "This button is for internal use by authorized app testers") and use this button as an entry point for the demo account. Another option is to distribute the app using Enterprise Distribution instead of through the AppStore.

Comment: Yeah. That's the only way I could find as well. Thank you for the help.