# iPhone CodeSign failed

Tags: iphone, xcode, codesign

So - I am a registered iPhone developer (Having paid my $99/year). I have followed all the steps provided by Apple to get the provisioning and code-signing files. However, when I click 'build', it says:

`"Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate. (-19011)"`

I have re-downloaded all of the certificates and profiles repeatedly, and it still won't work. However, if I click 'build' (and it says codesign failed), but then drag the product .app file to my device in the organizer or click "Run", it will run on my device. Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invalid iPhone Application Binary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47941/invalid-iphone-application-binary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are able to run the .app on your device, your problem might be that you have buildt it with your developer provision profile. That won't work. You need to build it with a distribution provisioning profile for App store.

Apple provides good information of how to do this, but I think the info is kind of hidden in all this itunesconnect/provisioning portal stuff... Check this link: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/manage/distribution/index.action . There you sould see two important points: 
"Create and download your iPhone Distribution Provisioning Profile for App Store Distribution"
"Building your Application with Xcode for Distribution"

Good luck :-)

Comment: Thanks! I checked out Apples information and you are right, it was kind of hidden. It turned out that while I had the proper profiles set up in the project settings, those settings had not propagated to the target (Which Apples docs say you need to change as well, but I never knew that, they were hidden, LOL). Now its working fine, thanks a ton! You are a lifesaver.

Answer (score 0):

Does your profile show up in Xcode's Organizer window? (If not, drag the files from Finder to Xcode.)

What profile is selected in your Xcode project settings? Are you building debug, release, or for distribution?

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible causes of the -19011 code verification error (as evidenced by the [dozens of near identical stackoverflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22failed%20codesign%22%20%22-19011%22) about it). The specific cause is hinted at in the detail of the message (see [Apple Technical note TN2250 advice on the -19011 issue](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TNTAG32) for details)

In my case the error detail contained the phrase "Failed to load provision profile from:" after which I discovered that having spaces or special characters in the app OR the xcode scheme name can cause codesign verification fail.