# Application failed codesign verification.

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone CodeSign failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593180/iphone-codesign-failed)

From last two days i am facing following error when i want to run my xcode on real device for that i am using developer profile (provisioning profile) not distribution profile. 
i checked all the certificate in key chain.
So, please suggest me proper step by step procedure for removing this error.b'cos i don't have another device so i am unable to check it on device.

Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate. (-19011)  this error occurred for development profile

Thanks & Regards,
Priyanka.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have been installing Xcode betas recently, you might want to do a clean reinstall of your non-beta Xcode. I had codesign problems recently after installing the beta (something to do with it changing the tools).

Comment: you might also use `xcode-select` command in that case. After installation of beta versions you can switch your environment back to the official version.

Answer (score 0):

check in your Xcode project settings if the right profile is set. For example if you have changed the allowed devices in itunes connect you will have to assign the new profile again.

1. Goto the very first item on the left side (your project)
2. select your target
3. select the "Build Settings" Tab
4. search for code signing identity

Answer (score 0):

1. Register the Device's UDID in the provisioning portal
2. Make sure that you have specifically added the device to a developer provisioning profile.
3. Download that profile and drag it to XCode (if you are replacing a previous profile with the same name it is good practice to go into organizer and delete the old profile first so you don't get confused with 2 profiles with the same name.
4. Make sure that in both the project build settings and the target build settings that you specify the new profile for debug.
5. If you are using entitlements you may need to re-create them.