# iPhone Application Loader app store submission errors help

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, submission

I am trying to submit my app to the app store using the application loader. I get to the stage where I select the .app to send and it fails with these two errors, could any one help me with how to fix these?

`Info.plist does not contain a CFBundleResourceSpecification`

Not sure what the above means... on iTunes connect the bundle id is `com.<domain>.<appname>` and that is the same in Info.plist

`Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate.`

The properties of the project has the Codesign - "any iOS device" set to `iPhone Distribution  - recommended` So no idea what's going, how do I clear all profiles and certificates to start afresh as can't seem to resolve this one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely to be something wrong with the app signing, check out this question:

[Invalid iPhone Application Binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47941/invalid-iphone-application-binary)