# Invalid Binary Itunes Connect

Tags: binary, app-store-connect, iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Invalid iPhone Application Binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47941/invalid-iphone-application-binary)

Im ripping my hair out over this!!!

I have tried like everything and evertime i submit my app to itunes connect it allways says:

> Upload Received

(2 minutes Later)

> Invalid Binary

Its Driving me mad and i have already:

- Cleaned all builds
- Made a new Entitlement.plist
- Checked that it built with The
  Distribution Profile.

Comment: +1 so you can use some points to get the hair implanted back :P

Answer (score 34):

check up your mailbox associated with your apple developer account, apple will send email to your mailbox with some diagnose information and how to solve your problem.

for me, apple send following diagnose information. I actually have never touched iCound, which is really confusing. after all, I created a new app id without Wild-card character, then a new distribution profile, and sign my app, finally summit to apple, which turn out to be successful.

> Invalid Code Signing Entitlements - The signature for your app bundle contains entitlement values that are not supported. For the com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers entitlement, the first value in the array must consist of the prefix provided by Apple in the provisioning profile followed by a bundle identifier suffix. The bundle identifier must match the bundle identifier for one of your apps or another app that you are permitted to use as the iCloud container identifier.
>
> Specifically, value "K8FN29QYP2.*" for key "com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers" in ProductName is not supported.
>
> Invalid Code Signing Entitlements - The signature for your app bundle contains entitlement values that are not supported.
>
> Specifically, value "K8FN29QYP2.*" for key "com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier" in ProductName is not supported.

Comment: Also, if you use Gmail check your Spam folder. My errors from Apple were being filtered there.

Comment: The email was quick. I got: Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key "CFBundleIconFile": icon.png

Answer (score 9):

I have also faced this kind of Problem and I have got this kind of Response from Apple store .

> Dear Developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent binary submission for "**Application Name**". Before your app can be reviewed, the following issues must be corrected:
>
> Invalid Icon Path - No icon found at the path referenced under key "CFBundleIcons": icon114.png
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, go to the Version Details page and click Ready to Upload Binary. Continue through the submission process until the app status is Waiting for Upload and then use Application Loader to upload the corrected binary.
>
> Regards,
>
> The iTunes Store Team

Comment: I've read through all the answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47941/invalid-iphone-application-binary. And this is the only answer that has feedback from apple. My problem was because that I happened to reference non-existent images in my Info.plist and got resolved by removing those references.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this by adding two new keys to my entitlements plist - application-identifier and keychain-access-groups:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>application-identifier</key>
    <string>T9YRD11G97.com.duncancampbell.fontagious</string>
    <key>get-task-allow</key>
    <true/>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>T9YRD11G97.com.duncancampbell.fontagious</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I got the "T9YRD11G97" from AppID in the provisioning profile, and the "com.duncancampbell.fontagious" from the BundleID in iTunesConnect.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

When attempting to update my app, I experienced this problem as well. The only real change to my app since I last submitted it was the addition of iCloud support. I suspected something was wrong with my entitlements, and the error email I got from the itunesconnect@apple.com submit bot was very fishy. The relevant portion read:

```
Specifically, value "XXXXXXXXXXX.com.mydomain.myappmame" for key
"com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers" in 
MyAppName is not supported.
```

I've anonymized the app/domain/team id here to MyAppName / mydomain.com / XXXXXXXXXX. Note that the complaint says "XXXXXXXXXXX.com.mydomain.myappmame" is incorrect. Indeed it is incorrect. It should be "myappname", not "myappmame" with an 'm' instead of 'n'. I looked in the entitlement file in my project, and it was correct. I looked at the entitlement file included in the app bundle I submitted to the store, and it was correct. I unzipped the zip file I submitted to the store, and the entitlements file was correct there as well. So clearly this character substitution was happening ***after*** the app submission was accepted by the App Store.

Surely this problem doesn't affect everyone, or there would be a mass outcry. So I figured it likely that there's something "special" about my app that invokes a bug in the automated App Store submit processing. To verify, I created a new empty app from scratch, enabled iCloud entitlements, and submitted it to the App Store with a new app identifier. It was accepted and status changed to "waiting for review". So it passed muster. (I rejected the binary immediately so it wouldn't be reviewed :)

I managed to work around the problem by changing my entitlements file:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers</key>
    <array>
        <string>$(TeamIdentifierPrefix)com.mydomain.myappname</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

to this:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers</key>
    <array>
        <string>XXXXXXXXXX.com.mydomain.myappname</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

My hope was that whatever code in the App Store that performs the team identifier prefix was the culprit, and was somehow corrupting a character farther down the string. By doing that substitution myself, perhaps the corruption wouldn't occur and my app would go through. Surprise! It worked.

I wasted a day trying to figure this one out, and haven't heard back from Apple support yet. But it's sort of academic, since my app is now waiting for review. But I would still like to know what caused this, and that it's been fixed by Apple. If I ever find out, I'll update this posting.

Comment: I am having invalid build. I have one app with my framework as dependancy with bundleID say(com.abc.sample1)  and is submitted to app store. Now I am trying to upload second app with same framework in it and same bundle ID, to iTunes Connect, it says invalid build. If I change the framework's bundle ID to other than i already uploaded, than it works but not with same. I wanted to know if i can make a universal type of build to upload to.

Answer (score 0):

In my Case I expand the CFBundleIcons dictionary and then checked the icon name in CFBundleIconFiles. there was the old name of my icon so I updated it and it worked for me.