# Itune connect invalid binary status

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, armv7

i have x code 4.6.2.

development target is iOS 4.3.

armv7 is the architecture

i am trying to upload to app store 
submitted successfully.
but status changed from upload received to `invalid binary`.

i have revoke the certificate try multiple way but same problem is presisting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796482/invalid-binary-itunes-connect

Answer (score 0):

there are many many reasons will cause a invalid binary 
wrong Default.png? no Screen shot? etc.
Normally, the iTunes Connect will send you a email about the detail, you had better check your email for the detail.

Comment: yet not received any emails from yesterday.

Comment: have you seen the resolution button in iTunes Connect ? or have you validated the app in XCode->Organizer->Archive?