# The signature was invalid or or it was not signed with iPhone distribution certificate coming along

Tags: iphone, certificate

I am having same error, but my case is different. Please let me know different things below.

The email id for the request certificate should be same as the email id of iOS developer account and should be same as iTunes uploading account.

in my case the id which i bind with request certificate (abc@abc.com) is same as dev account (login to dev site for creating profile and all - abc@abc.com) and its different when i upload to iTunes (xyz@abc.com)

Please help me in this case, here are some confusion, and due to this I am getting this above subject error.

There is no invalid code sign it comes when I upload to iTunes via app loader.

Comment: Have you looked here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47941/invalid-iphone-application-binary

Comment: yes, i have looked there, but i have some confusion and i did this thrice, but its not working form me

Comment: have you tried clearing derived data, and clean build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved my issues.

iTunes allowed me to upload the app with other id which was sub id of master id.