# iPhone:App do not submit on app store

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Invalid iPhone Application Binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47941/invalid-iphone-application-binary)

I have tried to submit my app on app store 5 to 6 times but when I check status on itunesConnect the status is "Invalid Binary"

Base SDK of my app is 5.0
Deplyment target is 4.0

my app is only for iphone not for ipad

and moreover I have completed all steps to submit the app from pc successfully.

I can't understand why this error generates.

Any help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

You should contact Apple - logged into iTunes Connect, there is a link ("Contact Us") especially for this reason: `Having a problem uploading your application? Can't find a Finance Report? Use our Contact Us system to find an answer to your question or to generate a question to an iTunes Rep.`